# Jquery: Replace image while keeping the same size

Tags: jquery

I already know how to replace an image, but is there a way to do it while keeping the same size as the original image?

Comment: Explain further. If you replace an image, its dimensional values are default. You probably have some markup what needs to be removed.

Comment: If there is an image that is 100x100 and another that is 50x50. I want to replace them with an image that is 200x200. but I want the image to resize to fit the original image.

Comment: this is what I have

<script>
$('img[src*="image1"]').replaceWith('<img src="image2"/>');
</script>

Comment: Since you're replacing full image DOM elements, I suggest you use the same class on them and do similarly to what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to set the image size, then whatever src you put - it's going to be stretched to that size.

The example below will change the image source one second after you run it while preserving the size.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#myImg').attr('src', 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5oOkeGTIaNI/VRZ_MvQmrjI/AAAAAAAABYo/AJE_6NVu85Y/s1600/Super_mario.png');
  }, 1000);
```

```css
#myImg {width: 100px; height: 100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="myImg" src="http://www.mariogame.info/images/icon-facebook.png" />
```

Comment: Yeah, just saw your comment, that can work, too, just make sure you properly select the images using CSS (same class name, or maybe reference their container > img, etc).